# How to configure a custom Protostream serialization context initializer for Wildfly Infinispan subsystem?

Tags: java, protocol-buffers, wildfly, infinispan

I have a Wildfly application with an Infinispan cache containing objects that require custom serialization.

The Infinispan documentation for [Marshalling and Encoding Data](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.1.x/titles/encoding/encoding.html) recommends to use the protobuf-based *Protostream* marshaller.

I have generated the Protostream marshaller and *serialization context initializer* for the custom objects as described in the corresponding [documentation section](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.1.x/titles/encoding/encoding.html#marshalling_user_types).

I have also configured the cache container to use "PROTOSTREAM" marshaller via the Wildfly [Infinispan subsystem configuration attribute](https://docs.wildfly.org/24/wildscribe/subsystem/infinispan/cache-container/index.html#attr-marshaller):

```
<cache-container marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" ... ><!-- ... --></cache-container>
```

How can I configure the Wildfly Infinispan subsystem to use my custom *serialization context initializer*?

According to the Infispan documentation section on [Registering serialization context initializers](https://infinispan.org/docs/12.1.x/titles/encoding/encoding.html#registering-sci-embedded-caches_marshalling), there are two mechanisms:

1. Automatic detection via `java.util.ServiceLoader`
2. Manual registration via `serialization/context-initializer`

The documentation warns that

> If you manually register one `SerializationContextInitializer` implementation, it disables automatic registration. You must then manually register all other implementations.

Now, Wildfly itself already registers various *serialization context initializers* of its own.
Consequently, automatic detection is disabled.

Is there a way to **declaratively** configure custom *serialization context initializers* via **Wildfly Infinispan subsystem configuration**?

(Note that the custom *serialization context initializer* implementation is generated by the annotation processor into the *"target/"* folder.
Thus, I want to avoid *programmatic* registration because that would involve either loading that class by name or creating a separate project in order to reference that implementation class.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Now, Wildfly itself already registers various serialization context
> initializers of its own. Consequently, automatic detection is
> disabled.

WildFly will automatically load any `SerializationContextInitializer` instances (via `ServiceLoader`) that are visible from the modules associated with your cache-container. This means that you need to package your key/value types along with the associated `SerializationContextInitializer` instances enumerated within `/META-INF/services/org.infinispan.protstream.SerializationContextInitializer` as a WildFly module and associate this module with your cache-container.
e.g.

```
<cache-container name="foo" marshaller="PROTOSTREAM" modules="org.wildfly.clustering.infinispan.spi com.acme.bar">
   <!--...-->
</cache-container>
```

This will configure the "foo" cache-container with ProtoStream marshalling using both WF's default set of `SerializationContextInitializer` instances and your custom marshallers packaged within the "com.acme.bar" module.

See the WF docs specifics on creating a custom module.

I realize the need to create a custom module is awkward. I am hoping to simplify the process of configuring deployment specific cache-containers in a future release.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation! 
Does the _modules_ configuration have to be on the **cache-container** or can be set on the cache itself (e.g., on the **replicated-cache**)?
I'm asking because the _cache-container_ is initialized before my deployment, while the _replicated-cache_ is only initialized lazily during deployment, when the deployment module (named "deployment.com.acme.bar.ear") is already visible.

Comment: The Infinispan marshaller is configured at the cache-container level, thus the modules attribute is associated with the cache-container, not individual caches.

Comment: You workaround this limitation by wrapping your keys and values with objects that support lazily marshalled values.  This is how WF internally uses infinispan (for HttpSession attribute and @Stateful EJB caching), so that we can safely store deployment specific classes.